# PHP date_default_timezone_set() Resulting In Incorrect Time For Africa/Lagos

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

My server is Central Time and I'm trying to display an event for Abuja, Nigeria (displaying in their time).

My PHP code for displaying the correct time zones is as follows...

```
// since our server is central time we have to make the server think it's in a different time zone or it will display all times using the central offset
// date_default_timezone_set("bleh") is used to do this
// php supported time zones (http://us3.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)
// you have to specify every time zone (even odd-balls like Napal) if you want every time zone to work correctly
if ($pubDatetimezone == "PST" || $pubDatetimezone == "PDT") date_default_timezone_set("America/Los_Angeles");
if ($pubDatetimezone == "MST" || $pubDatetimezone == "MDT") date_default_timezone_set("America/Denver");
if ($pubDatetimezone == "CST" || $pubDatetimezone == "CDT") date_default_timezone_set("America/Chicago");
if ($pubDatetimezone == "EST" || $pubDatetimezone == "EDT") date_default_timezone_set("America/Montreal");
// shows the incorrect time but the correct time zone (WAT)
if ($pubDatetimezone == "WAT") date_default_timezone_set("Africa/Lagos");
// displays the correct time but the incorrect time zone (AZOT)
// if ($pubDatetimezone == "WAT") date_default_timezone_set("Atlantic/Azores");
```

The American time zones work just fine, but the African time zone is displaying incorrectly.  The date/time should show `Friday, November 01, 2013 @ 6:00pm WAT` but it is showing `Friday, November 01, 2013 @ 8:00pm WAT`.

My server time is decently correct (within a few minutes of the correct time and the correct time zone).  The XML data that I'm importing has the correct date/time `<pubDate>Fri, 01 Nov 2013 18:00:00 WAT</pubDate>`.  It could be worth noting that I'm using a Windows server, IIS 7, and PHP 5.3.10.

WAT doesn't use daylight saving time.  Even if it did, then the time would only be 1 hour off and it's 2 hours off.  We ended up having to put incorrect times in our XML so that PHP would display correct times.

Any ideas as to what's wrong?

Comment: Have you tried updating the timezone database? (http://pecl.php.net/package/timezonedb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timezones database in PHP got deprecated. The best thing you can do is upgrade PHP to the latest 5.3. Apart from up-to-date timezones you'll get all the latest security fixes - the version 5.3.10 is pretty old and there were quite a few security issues fixed.

Unfortunately it's impossible to update only timezones db in PHP on Windows, as it's compiled into the binary files.

Comment: Hmmm...It looks like the newest version available through Web Platform Installer may be 5.3.13 (from 5/7/2012).  That's unfortunate.  I see that I can download Windows binaries.  Is it just a simple install/overwrite?  I don't see documentation with the binaries.  I'm using IIS.

Comment: It looks like I can just extract the new .zip into a new directory and point IIS to it.  I did notice some parts missing, like php_pdo_sqlsrv.dll and php_sqlsrv.dll (I use MSSQL).  Can missing files just be copied into the new directory or do other things need to be done?

Comment: You can always try just stop IIS completely, overwrite PHP files with the newest binaries available from php.net and check if it works. If you need more php extensions, get them from PECL or extract from the PHP distributive with installer (it includes much more extensions than .zip). I wouldn't recommend using older extensions with new PHP - can result in instability or immediate crash

Comment: Yes I could.  I think I might want to back up that directory, first, though.  Hehehe...